# HTML5 Web SQL Dynamic Size

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webkit, web-sql

With the following segment:

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
```

I need to be able to have a dynamically sized database.  Will the above database expand beyond the recommended size, or will it simply start throwing errors?  Is there a workaround for this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space)

An arbitrary limit of 5MB per origin (website, app, etc) is recommended, and placed on all web storage.

To simply, I would make the database size limit :  `5 * 1024 * 1024`   (5MB)

To answer your specific question, at least on an iPhone, that variable is described as the maxSize by [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase/UsingtheJavascriptDatabase.html)

Comment: I am using a plugin for phonegap that uses the websql api but treats the database different and doesn't have a quota.  What I need to know is whether or not the database size limit is static on existing databases, or if that parameter is even required

Comment: Since your websql code is being run in an iOS web frame it has all the limitation of Safari Mobile as defined by apple.  Including the 5 MB limit on all stored data.  If you created the database via SQL lite or CoreData, and then created an interface for it through phonegap down to some javascript functions, you could get around that limit.  You would not be using the "openDatabase" method then though.  I believe the parameter is static, and required.  When creating sql databases a size limitation is usually required.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  Have you used phonegap at all, or the SQLite plugin for it?

Comment: Yes, I've used PhoneGap, and a little of the SQLite plugin.  For the production app we did not use the SQLite Plugin, and opted for the html5 storage, and we just worked with the 5MB limit.  Additionally you could use a service like PARSE (no affliction) to offload some of the data to keep you in the 5MB limit.

Comment: Are there any issues, that you know of, regarding data persistency?  We absolutely cannot have data going missing randomly

Comment: The data will persist as long as the user does not clear it via    General Settings -> Safari -> Clear Cookies and Data

Comment: Okay, gonna pick your brain a little more.  Thanks so much for the help, Scott!  1) If 5mb is the limit per database, is there a limit on the number of 5mb databases that you can have?  2)Do you know if the cookies and data issue persists on to the sqlite plugin as well? 3) Where there technical reasons that your company went with web sql over the sqlite plugin?  If so, could you detail these.?  We are in the process of a MAJOR transition, so the more information you can give me the better!

Comment: Also, can the user clear the database info within android as well in the same manner?

Comment: 1) It is a global limit - 5MB total   2) Not sure what you mean, they are persisting in an HTML5 cache, so if the user clears it, it is gone.  If they don't clear it, then it will remain.  3)  We were building on several eco systems, and wanted to reduce any device unique code as much as possible.  By keeping the database in html5, it was all in javascript.  Otherwise we would of had to maintain an objective-c, java, and .Net database interface layer through PhoneGap, for iPhone, Android and Windows phone respectively.